# How can I ensure all requests go through an interceptor stack?

Tags: struts2

When working in Struts2, it is just too easy to create a template and refer a URL to it without creating an associated Action. Struts2 merrily renders the template -- which is fine in most cases, but not in our case: in order to ensure proper selection of a locale, we need all our requests go through a minimal interceptor stack.

We've been researching these two ways, both unsuccessfully:

1. Defining a "default action" which
   would be executed for any template
   which doesn't have an associated
   action.
2. Disabling the ability to
   render templates without an action
   -- this would force programmers to define actions for any template,
   which is a good solution too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe look into the wildcard mappings.

```
<action name="*" class="struts2you.examplelogin.BaseActionSupport">
    <result name="success">{1}.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If you place something like this as the first action I think all your unmapped jsp will be run through the default interceptor stack which you can define in struts.xml

Then also place your jsp files under the WEB-INF directory to prevent direct access

Comment: We've done this -- a little trickier because we don't use XML to configure Struts, but annotations, so priority is not that clear. But sufficient for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> When working in Struts2, it is just too easy to create a template and refer a URL to it without creating an associated Action.

Since Struts2 is an MVC framework, every request to it should invoke an action class and therefore go through an interceptor stack. I assume that you mean that you have JSPs that are not under WEB-INF and so they can be invoked directly via URL. That's generally a poor practice in the MVC world, as your JSPs should only represent the view layer. Place the JSPs somewhere under WEB-INF and all requests will be forced to go through an action, which will resolve your problem.

As for the choices, I would advocate creating explicit mappings for each of your templates.

Comment: You're right. We will adopt this solution in our next release. Thanks.